# Is there a nonmeasurable set in R in which all the measurable subsets are countable?

Tags: measure-theory

I think because there exist so many uncountable zero measure sets, it ought to be very easy to create a counterexample. However I failed to get an idea about this.

Comment: Do you mean a non-measurable set whose measurable subsets are all countable?

Answer (score 15):

That is the *definition* of a [Sierpiński set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_set): an uncountable set (or equivalently, a non-measurable set) whose every measurable subset is countable. The existence of a Sierpiński set of real numbers is independent of ZFC (standard set theory including the axiom of choice), but follows from the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis).

To construct a Sierpiński set using the continuum hypothesis, we use the fact that every set of Lebesgue measure zero is contained in a $G_\delta$ set of measure zero. Enumerate all the $G_\delta$ sets (or all the Borel sets) of measure zero in a transfinite sequence $A_\alpha,\ \alpha\lt\omega_1.$ Choose recursively points
$$x_\alpha\in\mathbb R\setminus\left(\{x_\beta:\beta\lt\alpha\}\cup\bigcup_{\beta\lt\alpha}A_\alpha\right);$$
then $X=\{x_\alpha:\alpha\lt\omega_1\}$ is a Sierpiński set.

On the other hand, it is consistent with ZFC (see [Martin's axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin%27s_axiom)) that every set of real numbers of cardinality $\aleph_1$ has Lebesgue measure zero. In that case, there are certainly no Sierpiński sets, seeing as every uncountable set has a subset of cardinality $\aleph_1.$

Comment: Do you have any idea whether there exists, in general, a set of size $\mathfrak c$ whose every measurable subset has size $<\mathfrak c$? That is a natural followup question, one you can't dodge via Martin's axiom. :)

Comment: @tomasz If $\mathfrak c=\aleph_2$ and $\mathbb R$ is the union of $\aleph_1$ sets of Lebesgue measure zero, then every set of reals of size $\mathfrak c$ contains a measure zero set of size $\mathfrak c.$ I believe the statement "$\mathfrak c=\aleph_2$ and $\mathbb R$ is the union of $\aleph_1$ sets of measure zero" is consistent with ZFC, but I'm not a set theorist and don't really understand such things.

Comment: Actually that works, as far as I can tell. More precisely, it is enough for it to be true that ${\bf R}$ is the union of $\kappa$ sets of measure zero with $\kappa$ smaller than the cofinality of $\mathfrak c$. But the fact that it is possible follows from the Cichoń's diagram: this $\kappa$ is the covering number of the measure ideal which can be strictly smaller than the cofinality of the measure ideal, which *I think* is at most as big as the cofinality of the continuum.

Comment: You can probably also force it directly without much difficulty, but my forcing is also not quite up to par. ;-)